# Need to remove 'New!' icon for new items added in Document Library

Tags: 2010, document-library

In our organization 'New!' icon is creating some confusion. Is it possible to remove the icon for some specific libraries only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken is per Site Collection only that you configure (or disable) the New Icon (set it to 0 to remove it completely).

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv Number_Of_Days -url http://sp-webApp
```

On the other hand you could easily replace its functionality in the web parts where you really need it with simple XSLT tricks.

To simply hide the actual icon in selected web parts use CSS

```css
.ms-vb img { display: none; }
```

Comment: The days-to-show-new-icon is per webapplication ([SPWebApplication.DaysToShowNewIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.daystoshownewindicator.aspx))

Comment: @C.Marius If I run the stsadm command, will it affect all libraries? Or it can be done for a specific library also?. Thx.

Comment: It'll be all libraries in that WebApplication

Comment: I didn't want to edit the original answer but the CSS above will hide the image for billeted lists too. `.ms-listviewtable .ms-vb IMG { display: none
}` will hide it just for table views.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Content editor web part and override new icon style to display none .This is applicable to (SharePoint online classic experience, 2013, 2010) not applicable for (modern experience)

```
<style> 
.icon-class-name
{
Display :none ;
}
</style>
```

2. Use column formatting to hide icon for SharePoint online modern experience